# Excel: create folder VBA script - get value from selected cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am using a VBA code to create a new folder in a directory. What I want to do is get the new folder name from the selected cell. Any ideas how I can do this please?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
If Target.Column = Range("B1").Column Then
  If Target.Row > 7 Then

'Variable definitions
Dim FolderListRange As Range
Dim FolderRange As Variant
Dim FolderName As String
Dim ParentFolderPath As String

On Error GoTo Handle
    ' Set the Folder where the individual folders should be created
    ParentFolderPath = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups"

    Set FolderListRange = Range("B" & Target.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    For Each FolderRange In FolderListRange

        FolderName = ParentFolderPath & "\" & FolderRange.Value

        If FileSystem.Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
            FileSystem.MkDir FolderName
        End If

Continue:
    Next

Handle:
  End If
  End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
Dim folderNameCell As Range
Dim newFolderName As String

Set folderNameCell = Application.Selection
newFolderName = folderNameCell.Value
```